# What is the best way to protect a digital goods directory so that it can only be accessed by a PHP script?

Tags: php, permissions, download, password-protection

My site interacts with the PayPal Digital Goods API which on completion redirects back to my PHP script which then allows the download.

I would like to know the best way to protect the directory containing digital goods which is outside of the web root.

At the moment I am protecting the directories by removing all permissions. When the download script is called the permissions of the directory containing the digital good are changed to allow the download then removed again. Below is a shorthand version of what's happening in the script.

> ```
> chmod('/digital/goods/directory/file', 0777);
> readfile(file);
> chmod('/digital/goods/directory/file', 0000);
> ```

I'am sure this cant be the right way to do this. Could you use htaccess without the user having to enter the user and password? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds fairly unnecessary - you should work out a permission set that always allows *you* to access the files, but no one else. What kind of attack are you trying to protect against? What kind of web server is this running on? Do you share it with others, or is it your own?

Comment: outside the web root should be enough, in 99% of situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure the files aren't being served directly.  In Apache, you would keep them out of the [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot).

Then, the permissions shouldn't matter, since there is simply no URL that maps to them.

Comment: I think I know what I was doing wrong. I had previously set an alias in my apache httpd.conf which linked to my digital goods directory, I set it so that linking to the directories in my scripts was simpler however it also made the digital goods directory available in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Store your digital goods above the DocumentRoot, and then serve via a PHP script with a unique hash for each purchaser

ie)

DocumentRoot: /home/user/public_html/store

Protected Folder /home/user/goods

With PHP use:
Readfile() see http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

and use something like this to serve the file:

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('/home/user/goods/original.pdf');
?>
```